# Array initializer and pointer confusion

Tags: c, pointers

I've learnt that the square brackets `[]` are really just pointer operators ie

```
array[n] == *(array + n)
```

But how does this work in the context of initializing an array of size `n`? For example

```
int array[n]
```

Is this the same as `int *(array + n)`? Doesn't feel correct.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges: acessing array elements vs. creating a new array. Also, please tag a language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declarators in declarations appear similar to expressions because they provide a sort of picture of the identifier being used. As Kernighan and Ritchie wrote in *The C Programming Language*, 1978, page 90:

> The declaration of the pointer `px` is new.
>
> `int *px;`
>
> is intended as a mnemonic; it says the combination `*px` is an `int`, that is, if `px` occurs in the context `*px`, it is equivalent to a variable of the type `int`. In effect, the syntax of the declaration for a variable mimics the syntax of expressions in which the variable might appear.

However, this mirroring of expressions is limited to a few specific forms and combinations of them: pointers, arrays, and function calls. Thus, we can write `int *p` to declare a pointer, `int a[3]` to declare an array, and `int f(void)` to declare a function, but we cannot write `int x+3` to declare something to which 3 is added or `int *(a+4)` to declare a pointer to the first element of an array to which 4 is added.

Declarators use a grammar specified in C 2018 6.7.6 that allows the use of these few constructions, while expressions use a separate and much richer grammar specified in 6.5.

Answer (score 2):

> I've learnt that the square brackets [] are really just pointer operators

This is only when they are being used in the context of being a binary operator.

```c
/* in this case, [] is being used to specify the size of the array, it is not
   being used as an indexing operator */
int a[n];
/* in this case, [] is being used as an indexing operator, so the following two are equivalent */
do_something(a[i]);
do_something(*(a+i));
```

The first line is an example of a declaration, which is parsed differently than a typical expression.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` operator means different things in declarations and expressions.

In a declaration, the `[]` in the declarator only means the thing you're declaring has an array *type* (you're not attempting to index into it here) - the declaration

```
int array[10];
```

sets aside space for 10 `int` objects, like so:

```
       +---+
array: |   | array[0]
       +---+
       |   | array[1]
       +---+
        ...
       +---+
       |   | array[9]
       +---+
```

You initialize an array in a declaration using a brace-enclosed list of initializers.  Arrays of character type (`char` or `wchar_t`) can be also initialized using string literals.  If no dimension is specified (you have an empty `[]`), then the array size is determined by the number of elements in the initializer.  If there are fewer elements in the initializer than the array is sized to hold, then elements not explicitly initialized are implicitly initialized to zeros or `NULL`, depending on the element type.  Examples:

```
int a[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int b[]   = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8};                 // size of array determined by number of elements in initializer
int c[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};                 // elements 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9 are implicitly initialized to 0
char str1[] = "foo";                         // size taken from length of string, including the 0 terminator
char str2[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', 0};            // identical to the above
```

In an *expression*, the `[]` operator is used to access the `i`'th element of the array.  Yes, the operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - under most circumstances<sup>1</sup>, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

This "decay" behavior is unique to array types. C is derived from an earlier language called B, which set aside space for an explicit pointer to the first element of an array, and array subscripting was done in terms of offsets from that pointer.  Ritchie wanted to keep B's array semantics, but he didn't want to keep the separate pointer those semantics required, so he created the rule that an array expression will "decay" to a pointer.

---

1. Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or it is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first pointer in the array.

Comment: Re “This "decay" behavior is unique to array types”: Lvalues are automatically converted to values, and function designators are automatically converted to pointers.